# My Magic 8 ball

Tags: python

My magic 8 ball code won't work for some reason. The basic code works but it wont give one answer, it starts some never ending loop. Any help?

```
import sys
import random

ans = True

while ans:
    question = input("Ask the magic 8 ball a question: (press enter to quit) ")

    answers = random.randint(1,8)

    if question == "":
        sys.exit()

    elif answers == 1:
        print ("It is certain")

    elif answers == 2:
        print ("Outlook good")

    elif answers == 3:
        print ("You may rely on it")

    elif answers == 4:
        print ("Ask again later")

    elif answers == 5:
        print ("Concentrate and ask again")

    elif answers == 6:
        print ("Reply hazy, try again")

    elif answers == 7:
        print ("My reply is no")

    elif answers == 8:
        print ("My sources say no")
```

Generally I would figure this out myself but I have been looking at it for two years

Comment: two *years*? :O

Comment: Look where `ans` is set (and where not)

Comment: Yeah, I made this while in year 9, I am now in year 11

Comment: The question of OP is not clear to me. Can anyone explain? It runs fine actually.

Comment: The loop runs forever because ans is true always. See @MichaelButscher 's suggestion.

Comment: `(press enter to quit)` when I press `enter` key it breaks the loop. So what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add ans = False at the end like this:

```
import sys
import random

ans = True

while ans:
    question = input("Ask the magic 8 ball a question: (press enter to quit) ")

    answers = random.randint(1,8)

    if question == "":
        sys.exit()

elif answers == 1:
    print ("It is certain")

    elif answers == 2:
        print ("Outlook good")

    elif answers == 3:
        print ("You may rely on it")

    elif answers == 4:
        print ("Ask again later")

    elif answers == 5:
        print ("Concentrate and ask again")

    elif answers == 6:
        print ("Reply hazy, try again")

    elif answers == 7:
        print ("My reply is no")

    elif answers == 8:
        print ("My sources say no")
    ans = False
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a loop, don't use a `while`.
For a 1 shot response, try this :

```
import random

answers = ("It is certain","Outlook good","You may rely on it",\
           "Ask again later","Concentrate and ask again",\
           "Reply hazy, try again","My reply is no","My sources say no")

if input("Ask the magic 8 ball a question: (press enter to quit) "):
    print( answers[random.randint(0,len( answers )-1)] )
```

Comment: For actually optimizing the program you can even use ``random.choice`` on the list.